# ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY) showing duplicate results for Group By Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2008, where-clause

I have the below query that was created to show the summation of the "Last" values for a year, usually this is a december value, but the year could potentially end in any month so i want to add together the last values for each goalmontecarloheaderid.  I have it working 99%, but there are some random duplicates in the [year] value.

```
WITH endBalances AS (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION By GoalMonteCarloHeaderID, Year(Convert(date,MonthDate)) Order By Max(Month(Convert(date,MonthDate))) desc) n, Max(Month(Convert(date,MonthDate))) maxMonth, GrowthBucket, WithdrawalBucket, NoTaxesBucket,
        Year(MonthDate) [year]
        From GoalMonteCarloMedianResults mcmr
        full join GoalMonteCarloHeader mch on mch.ID = mcmr.GoalMonteCarloHeaderID
        full join GoalChartData gcd on gcd.ID = mch.GoalChartDataID and gcd.TypeID = 2
        inner join Goal g on g.iGoalID = gcd.GoalID
        where g.iTypeID in (1) and g.iHHID = 850802
        group by GoalMonteCarloHeaderID, MonthDate, GrowthBucket, WithdrawalBucket, NoTaxesBucket
)
SELECT [year], Sum(GrowthBucket) GrowthBucket, Sum(WithdrawalBucket) WithdrawalBucket,Sum(NoTaxesBucket) NoTaxesBucket, maxMonth
From endBalances 
where [year] is not null and n=1
Group By [year], maxMonth
order by [year] asc
```

Showing two random duplicates in the database result;
[image]

you can see in the image there are two examples where the year is duplicated and displayed for more than just the 'last' month in the year.  Am I doing something wrong with the group by or the PARTITION BY() in my query?  I am not the most familiar with this functionality of T-SQL.

Comment: Removed the MySQL tag, because it doesn't seem related to this question at all

Comment: sorry typed 'sql' thought that was what i selected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

T-SQL has a lovely function for this which has no direct equivalent in MySQL.

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [year] ORDER BY MonthDate DESC) AS rn
```

Then anything with rn=1 will be the last entry in a year.

The answers to this question have a few ideas:
[ROW_NUMBER() in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql)

Comment: the only issue with that is that i am doing a summation in my dataset, sometimes there will be 2 or more december values for different 'goals' and in that case it will only take the last goal value not the summation of all three, but thank you for the idea i am implementing that exact logic in a different area.

Comment: Then partition by both [year] and GoalID, like you now have in your original post. That should work great.

Comment: I have re-worked my query and updated the post above, I am now receiving random duplicates for the years, i have also tried partitioning by the iGoalID from dbo.Goal table and receive the same results, do you know why I might be getting these dupes?  Thank you for all your help in this!

Comment: i figured it out, it was because of my grouping by the year and maxMonth columns, removed the maxMonth grouping and everything looks good!